# Inconsistent page clearing with \includeonly

Tags: double-sided, include

I'm writing my thesis using memoir.cls, with a top-level document for preamble and front matter and the like, and a source file per chapter, organised like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
  \include{intro}
  \include{a}
  \include{b}
  \include{conclusion}
\end{document}
```

To compile only the part of the document I'm working on at the moment, I use `\includeonly`, as you'd expect. Now, if I `\includeonly{a}` or `\includeonly{conclusion}` I get the output I expect, but if it's `intro` or `b` that's `\includeonly`-ed, the chapter opens on the left-hand side rather than the right-hand side as it should. There seems to be a stray `\newpage` getting inserted somehow.

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Perhaps you should try  `\usepackage{newclude}`. This prevents additional pagebreaks from the `\include` command.

Comment: Edit: Does this happen with `memoir` class only?

Comment: what exactly are in those included files?

Comment: I can see why this is annoying - but does the improper pagination really matter when you're working on a chapter at a time rather than the whole document?

Comment: It is not only `memoir` that does this, `book` does the same

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yeah, it's not a serious problem, just an annoyance.

Comment: But it also happens with book.cls. Since I have som styling as well, with book the frontmatter ends on a right hand side, so the additional clear means I end up with a completely blank double spread, which looks even sillier, actually.

Comment: I my test, I just have a `\chapter` in each of the four files, I only get a single page i in the `intro` case.

Comment: @Christian: newclude.sty doesn't look like it works with memoir. It complains about `\providelength` already being defined, which it looks like both of them define.

Comment: I've never seen it give a problem when all the files are included at once. could to add an example of that?

Comment: Oh sorry, it only happens when I compile single chapters. When I compile the whole shebang it's fine. It's just an aesthetic wart that's been annoying me. If fixing it is more involved than a small-ish bit of code, it's nothing I can't live with.

Comment: Regardless if it is aesthetic or not, but there might be cases where this 'flaw' is completely inappropiate -- if one wants to have several versions of a document, some of them including particular chapters and some excluding it, depending on one's needs.

Comment: if  \chapter is opening on an even page (and you havent'  used [openany]) that sounds like a bug and a complete working example would be useful (_all_ questions should have a working example:-)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "left hand side" what latex preserves is that the chapter heading appears on an odd numbered page, if you are just including part of the document the odd numbered page may in fact be on a side that is an even number in the print stack so will appear on the wrong side if simply printed duplex.

Comment: @daleif: So does `report` and `extreport`. Perhaps the [tag:memoir] tag is misplaced?

Comment: @krlmlr yes, the class is irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\includeonly{a}
\begin{document}

  \include{intro}
  \include{a}
  \include{b}
  \include{conclusion}
\end{document}
```

---

intro.tex

```
\chapter{intro}
intro
```

---

a.tex

```
\chapter{aa}
aa
```

---

b.tex

```
\chapter{bb}
bb
```

---

conclusion.tex

```
\chapter{conc}
conc
```

If you process the full document then uncomment the `\includeonly` you get just chapter 2 from `a.tex`.

First LaTeX checks the recorded data for the skipped chapter 1 and it ends on page 1 so the page counter is set to 1, then the included `a.tex` is input, the `\chapter` is seen which does `\cleardoublepage` so a blank page is thrown to skip page 2 and then the chapter heading starts on page 3.  this is a *right hand page* it has an odd page number and the odd page header footer and margins as set in the class. It is the second page in the stack as the first page output is page 2 (as you have specified to omit page 1) so if printing on paper rather than viewing on screen you need to take care of your printer settings.

This means that if you want `\includeonly` to work consistently you need to make sure that every chapter ends on an even page, so that the chapter head of the following chapter never needs to throw a blank page.  If you add `\cleardoublepage` to the end of each file then the blank page will be recorded as part of the previous chapter so when you `\includeonly{a}` then page 3 will be the first page printed, so the parity is kept.

Comment: updated with coding scheme that keeps the parity of pages.

Comment: @ebo normally `\cleardoublepage`  is not needed as the included files start with a command such as `\chapter` which automatically force the correct page parity.

Comment: Is there any way to automate the insertion of `\cleardoublepage` at the end of each chapter file?

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, that did not work for me (maybe the `\cleardoublepage` must be really inside the chapter file to be considered properly?)

Comment: @jpmath oh yes that's exactly what I said in my answer:-) I'll delete the comment.

Comment: No problem. :-) Do you think `\cleardoublepage` could be automatically inserted at the end of every chapter file?

Comment: easiest would be to take a copy of `\include` from latex.ltx sources and add \cleardoublepage just after the input (so it gets skipped if the input is being skipped)